# Finding the basis of all perpendicular vectors to two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$... How many vectors should this basis include?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been given this question in my textbook:

> Find a basis of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ that consists of all vectors perpendicular to both $(1, 0, -1, 1)$ and $(0, 1, 2, 3)$.

My question is how many vectors should be in the basis of perpendicular vectors, and how would I know how to find that? I initially thought it would be two vectors, but the number of unknowns seems to be too high for it to be possible to solve.

Also, if I am looking at this question in the wrong way, and there is a simpler solution, please let me know.

Comment: The number of unknowns is too high for a unique solution, but that's OK--there *isn't* a unique solution. Eliminate as many unknowns as you can, then plug in whatever values you like for the rest.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If $(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4$, then
$$
\langle(x,y,z,t),(1,0,-1,1)\rangle=0\iff x-z+t=0
$$
and
$$
\langle(x,y,z,t),(0,1,2,3)\rangle=0\iff y+2x+3t=0.
$$
So, the space of all vectors perpendicular to both $(1,0,-1,1)$ and $(0,1,2,3)$ is
$$
P=\left\{(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x-z+t=0\text{ and }y+2z+3t=0.\right\}.
$$
But
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
         x-z-t=0\\
         y+2z+3t=0
       \end{array}\right.
\iff
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
         x=z+t\\
         y=-2z-3t.
       \end{array}\right.
$$
A simple way of getting a basis of $P$ consists in taking the vector for which $z=1$ and $t=0$ together with the vector for which $z=0$ and $t=1$. In other words, the basis will be
$$
\{(1,-2,1,0),(1,-3,0,1)\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonality requirement yields the system
$$ \begin{cases}x-z+w &= 0 \\ y+2z+3w &= 0 \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \left ( \begin{array}{cccc}1&0&-1&1 \\ 0&1&2&3\end{array} \right )$$
Basically, a solution is already visible. The rank is two, hence two variables are free - for example $z$ and $w$. To get a basis, take values for $z$ and $w$ from any $2\times 2$ nonsingular matrix.